# Run macros and end if statement conditions satisfied

Tags: vba, excel

I have an IF Else statement that checks if a spreadsheet exists in the workbook. If it does exist, it is meant to run a particular macros, and then stop. If the spreadsheet does not exist, it should run to the end of the IF statement, and then generate a MSGBOX with an error message.

I can't get the IF statement to end once the condition is satisfied, and the macro has run.

The code is:

```
Dim k As Integer
Dim t As String
Dim x As Integer

k = Sheets.Count
x = 1

    While x <= k
        t = Sheets(x).Name
        If t = "Details" Then

            Call Details_1

        Else

            x = x + 1

        End If

    Wend

    If x > k Then

        MsgBox "Something seems to have gone wrong." & vbCrLf & "Please ensure that you have pressed 'Button 1' before you press any of the other buttons", vbOKOnly, "ERROR MESSAGE"

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean it calls Details_1 and then continues the While loop, which you don't want.
If so then I would suggest you change your code to something like this:

```
Dim k As Integer
Dim t As String
Dim x As Integer

k = Sheets.Count
x = 1

Do While x <= k
    t = Sheets(x).Name
    If t = "Details" Then

        Call Details_1
        Exit Do

    Else

        x = x + 1

    End If

Loop

If x > k Then

    MsgBox "Something seems to have gone wrong." & vbCrLf & "Please ensure that you have pressed 'Button 1' before you press any of the other buttons", vbOKOnly, "ERROR MESSAGE"

End If
```

This code should cycle through your sheets until it finds Details, call Details_1 and then continue with the next section of code

Answer (score 0):

Move `x = x + 1` so that it is after the first `End If`.  Right now after the macro is called the `x = x + 1` doesn't get executed and x is then always <= k.